# Are DICOM attributes always sorted by tag?

Tags: dicom

It seems to me that in all DICOM files I checked, the attributes are sorted by their tag, in increasing order, with the pixel data at the end. I checked the DICOM standard, but I cannot find anything on this.

Is the order of attributes in a DICOM file guaranteed?

Comment: Yes, this is demanded [by the standard](https://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part05.html#sect_7.1).

Comment: One quick comment: `the pixel data at the end` this is wrong statement.

Comment: @malat would you care to elaborate what is wrong about the statement that I made about files that I myself checked?

Comment: I see a few public tag listed *after* the [Pixel Data](https://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part06/chapter_6.html) tag, without counting the private ones. So you cannot assume pixel data is at end in all cases.

Comment: @malat yes, that is correct in the context of the dictionary. In the introductory sentence to my question, however, I was referring to "all DICOM files *I checked*", and that statement is still correct.

Comment: @malat so while you are right in the strict sense that there may come data after the pixel data, I have yet to see a file where that is the case, and that encourages me to implement a heuristic that computes the size of the pixel data from the first tags (which can be done fast), and then search backwards from the end of file to see if the pixel data attribute is there. Why, you ask? Because finding pixel data by iterating through all, sometimes tens of thousands of tags before the pixel data can be painfully slow. If the pixel data cannot be found this way, one can still fall back.

Comment: Just to clarify - my comment was about the tag order, not that the pixel data is at the end (I missed that part). And while it is true that most DICOM images don't have tags after the pixel data, I have seen a few that do. So your approach will work for most images as long as you don't rely on that.

Comment: Also note that this would only work for uncompressed data. You can't infer the size of PixelData with compressed transfer syntax from the other tags.